# Convert Binary Tree To Doubly Linked List - Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree, traversal

Help me with this problem please. It's taken from Educative.io course called "Coderust 3.0: Faster Coding Interview Preparation"

**Problem description:**

Convert a binary tree to a doubly linked list such that the order of the doubly linked list is the same as an in-order traversal of the binary tree. After conversion the left pointer of the node should be pointing to the previous node in the doubly linked list and the right pointer should be pointing to the next node in the doubly linked list.

[image: Here's a visualization of the problem]

**My Code:**

```
class toDLL{
  public static BinaryTreeNode convert_to_linked_list(BinaryTreeNode root) {

    Stack<BinaryTreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
    BinaryTreeNode head = root;
    if(root == null) return head;

    while(root != null) {
      head = root;
      stack.push(root);
      root = root.left;
    }

    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
      BinaryTreeNode temp = stack.pop();
      BinaryTreeNode cur = temp;

      cur = cur.right;
      while(cur != null) {
         stack.push(cur);
        cur = cur.left;
      }
      if(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        temp.right = stack.peek();
        stack.peek().left = temp;
      }
    }
    return head;
  }
}
```

When I run it inside educative.io compiler, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BinaryTree.get_list(*.java:39)
    at EdTestRunner.executeTests(*.java:374)
    at TestRunner.main(*.java:401)
```

However, when I run it inside Eclipse using my own BinaryTreeNode class implementation, **I get no errors**. My code for that class is pretty long so I believe I don't need to add it here?

I don't see how I could have a Null Pointer exception when I have so many checks that see if the stack is empty before doing any operations.

Help please

Comment: The error is on line 39 according to the message. Which line is 39?

Comment: I am also missing the `get_list` method in your code sample (which is also a bit incorrectly formatted, so the rendered version here isn't so easy to read). Please show us more excerpts of the code and I'm sure we'll be able to solve it together.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. I went to the solution and realized that they assumed the DoublyLinkedList was circular when they were testing it. That was careless of me and I should have looked at the error messages more carefully ! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Fixed it by adding this piece of code after my last if statement:

else {
        temp.right = head;
        head.left = temp;
      }

Comment: In general, things like BinaryTrees are perfect candidates for recursion.  In this case, the recursion would be: 1) if (root == null) { return null } else { <<return the concatenation of : [ recurse-left , current-node , recurse-right ] >> }